# Entity Framework Core commands are not recognized in Nuget PM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We are using EF6 and EF Core in the project at the same time. I have migration which was created by other team member. I want to Update database using next command:

EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database

But the next error is occured:

```
EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database : The module 'EntityFrameworkCore' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module EntityFrameworkCore'.
At line:1 char:1
+ EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

It writing, that the EF Core module could not be loaded, but it in the project packages folder, i checked it.

Import-Module EntityFrameworkCore command executing result:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'EntityFrameworkCore' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (EntityFrameworkCore:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I don`t understand why i can`t using it now, and why NPM can not fine EF Core module.

This packages in csproj file are mentioned:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="1.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic" Version="1.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Can somebody tell me, what i am doing wrong? Update-Database without EntityFrameworkCore prefix is recognized. .Net Framework 4.6.2

Comment: I might be misreading this, but I don't think you can use entity framework core within a .Net Framework context. You're application would need to be using a target framework of netcoreapp2.0.

Comment: @Jack my teammembers also have the same project configuration, and it working. And look at the version of the EF Core we using right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I had to change the way of working. I wrote this recipe to my mates, I hope it helps you:

"

1st.-  HOW TO ADD A MIGRATION:

```
Go to the project folder and type:
dotnet ef migrations add [NameOFYourMigrationGoesHere] -c YourContext
```

NOTE: Don't forget to add created files to source control, that's not done auto-magically

2nd.- HOW TO UPDATE YOUR DB's:
    2.a.- In docker -> You can run the project (entirely with Docker) and the migration would be applied at the first Context usage. 
            note: (It will use the configured connection string for that environment)

2.b.- Your Local DB -> Edit the Connection String hardcoded in ConfigurationContext.OnConfigure and run:

dotnet ef database update --context ConfigurationContext

**STEPS TO REPLICATE THIS FROM SCRATCH:**

Migration Commands has changed a lot in .Net Core
I recommend to visit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

1st.- You must add these lines to the .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note: Version might change

2nd.- Create a Context in your project like this:

public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    #region Constructors

```
public YourContext()
{
}

public YourContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{

}

#endregion Constructors

#region DbSets
#endregion DbSets

#region OnConfiguring
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    // In order to be able to create migrations and update database:
    if (!options.IsConfigured)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("YourLocalConnectionStringShouldBeHere");
    }
    base.OnConfiguring(options);
}
#endregion

#region Model Creating

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // Your Model Crerating Stuff
}

#endregion Model Creating
```

}

3rd.- Why not to create an "Initial" Migration according to steps above??

Happy coding!

"

I hope it helps you.

Juan

EDIT:

In addition, the real issue here is that there are different EF "flavours". Just go to EF root documentation and see the differences:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/

EF 6 migrations commands: https://dzone.com/articles/ef-migrations-command

EF Core migrations commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations

Now my answer seems complete to me. I hope this saved you time guys.

Comment: Thank you, Juan!  
I have update database from project folder just writing in windows power shell next command: `dotnet ef database update`
I am still don`t know why my previous command is not working, but your advice is very usefull for me!

Comment: Well, glad to help Aram... Other people said that it was because of different targeted frameworks, tools, commands and way of working are slightly different if you work with EF for .NET framework than if you use EF Core, the command you used is Core, as I said, I had similar issues the first time I used migrations within a .NET core solution (and my colleagues too) As I said, glad to help. KR,.   Juan